# How does flow relate to language competency? Can it be taught/learned?

Tags: learning-methods, reference-request, teaching-methods, proficiency

[Psychological flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) is kind of like going on autopilot, or
being completely immersed in an activity, and is also related to high
performance levels. I was reading about flow in  music, but it reminded
me of language learning and the [input hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_hypothesis): feeling awkward, self-conscious, or even bored while learning a language raises an affective filter
and inhibits learning effectiveness.

Is there any research demonstrating the presence of such a mental state in the context of L2 communication?

Also, is there research to support a connection between flow and language competency? Can such a state of mind be taught/learned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[K. Anders Ericsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K._Anders_Ericsson), the father of [deliberate practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practice_(learning_method)#Deliberate_practice) and expert on learning, pretty much destroys *flow* as a good learning method in [this](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1467-8721.2007.00533.x) article.

> It is clear that skilled individuals can sometimes experience highly
>   enjoyable states (‘‘flow’’ as described by [Mihaly Csikszentmihalyi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mihaly_Csikszentmihalyi),
>   1990) during their performance. These states are, however,
>   incompatible with deliberate practice, in which individuals engage in
>   a (typically planned) training activity aimed at reaching a level just
>   beyond the currently attainable level of performance by engaging in
>   full concentration, analysis after feedback, and repetitions with
>   refinement.

Furthermore:

> The commonly held but empirically unsupported notion that some
>   uniquely “talented” individuals can attain superior performance in a
>   given domain without much practice appears to be a destructive myth
>   that could discourage people from investing the necessary efforts to
>   reach expert levels of performance.

In short, aim to implement deliberate practice in your language learning life, not flow.

Comment: KA Ericsson's work seems to discredit the idea of "flow" as a tool for language learning. It definitely does if language learning can be viewed as learning a skill in the same way that the skills he researches are.